Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'image')
I'm now developing an e-commerce website using ReactJS. Now when I'm creating products page with . However, it show me the error of Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'image'). Can you guy help me with this error. Thank you!!
This is my ProductDisplay.jsx:
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import './ProductDisplay.css';
import star_icon from '../assets/star_icon.png';
import star_dull_icon from '../assets/star_dull_icon.png';

const ProductDisplay = (props) => {
    const {product} = props;
    return (
        <div className="productdisplay">
            <div className="productdisplay-left">
                <div className="productdisplay-img-list">
                    <img src={product.image} alt="" />
                    <img src={product.image} alt="" />
                    <img src={product.image} alt="" />
                    <img src={product.image} alt="" />
                </div>
                <div className="productdisplay-img">
                    <img className="productdisplay-main-img" src={product.image} alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="productdisplay-right">
                <h1>{product.name}</h1>
                <div className="productdisplay-right-star">
                    <img src={star_icon} alt="" />
                    <img src={star_icon} alt="" />
                    <img src={star_icon} alt="" />
                    <img src={star_icon} alt="" />
                    <img src={star_dull_icon} alt="" />
                    <p>(122)</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ProductDisplay;

This is my ShopContext.jsx:
import React, {createContext} from "react";
import all_products from "../components/assets/all_products";


export const ShopContext = createContext(null);

const ShopContextProvider = (props) => {

    const contextValue = {all_products};

    return(
        <ShopContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
            {props.children}
        </ShopContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default ShopContextProvider;

And this is the error:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'image')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'image')
at ProductDisplay (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1864:24)
at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:28709:22)
at mountIndeterminateComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:31993:17)
at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33289:20)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:18305:18)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:18349:20)
at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:18406:35)
at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38270:11)
at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:37518:16)
at workLoopSync (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:37441:9)
I tried to change the {product}, check the shopCategory, but the result was still the same or it didn't show anything

There's not really enough info here to help. Also please put code snippets in the question directly and not as external screenshots. All we can say for certain at this point is that product is undefined. Why? We'd probably need to know more about the context and how product is supposed to be set

The code in the question now is different than the code from the screenshot before.. With the code present now, we don't know anything about props because that piece is not included. With the code from the screenshot, you are trying to read a property from context called product, but your context value is called all_products.
